# Tkinter buttons disappear when window is resized

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the start of a simple text editor. Everything works, except if I make the window shorter, the buttons disappear. How can I solve this?

```
from tkinter import *

top = Tk()

def main():
    frame1 = Frame(top)   
    frame1.pack(side='top', fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame1, orient="vertical")
    text = Text(frame1, height=40, width=80, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.config(command=text.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill=Y)
    text.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

    frame2 = Frame(top)
    frame2.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
    
    loadButton = Button(frame2, text="Load", command=quit)
    spacer = Label(frame2, text='If the buttons disappear, make the window taller')
    quitButton = Button(frame2, text="Save and Quit", command=quit)
    
    loadButton.pack(side=LEFT, pady=12)
    spacer.pack(side=LEFT)
    quitButton.pack(side=RIGHT)
    
    
    mainloop()

def quit():
    top.withdraw()
    top.destroy()

    
main()
```

Comment: You need to call `frame2.pack(...)` before `frame1.pack(...)` because the order of packing affects which widget gets the available space first.

Answer (score 0):

Since you pack `frame1` first, so when the window is shrunk, `frame1` will get the available space first and `frame2` will be shrunk.

So packing `frame2` before `frame1` will solve your issue:

```
def main():
    frame1 = Frame(top)
    frame2 = Frame(top)

    # pack frame2 before frame1
    frame2.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
    frame1.pack(side='top', fill=BOTH, expand=True)

    ...
```